# When is a map essential in Čech cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I read a nice survey of parts of game theory, [Foundations of Strategic Equilibrium](http://homes.eco.auckland.ac.nz/jhil044/public_html/papers/pdf/steq_prn.pdf), by Hillas and Kohlberg. Something where I stumble is the discussion of Mertens stability. There is a definition that requires a certain map to be essential in Čech cohomology and I know nothing about cohomology. So I would like to know:

> Is there a self-contained way to define essentiality of a map in Čech
>   cohomology that can be explained to someone who knows point-set
>   topology quite well but knows almost nothing about algebraic topology?
>   If yes, please give the definition and maybe a bit of explanation..

Comment: What means "to be essential in Čech cohomology"?

Comment: @BorisNovikov That is the question. The whole thing appears at the end of page 45 and beginning of page 46 in the [linked text](http://homes.eco.auckland.ac.nz/jhil044/public_html/papers/pdf/steq_prn.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

Hillas has an excellent working paper where you can get a nice intuition of what such an essentiality condition implies. The title is "A Game Illustrating Some Features of the Definition of Strategic Stability".

Answer (score 1):

I found the paper where a correct definition of essentiality is given:

Srihari Govindan and Jean-Francois Mertens (1993): \An Equivalent Def-
inition of Stable Equilibria"

If you want I will send it by e-mail. As to Cech cohomology, there is the classical book

Spanier, Ediwin H (1966) Algebraic Topology. McGraw Hill, New York.

However it is very thick. I can recommend, e.g.,

Morgan J. W., Lamberson P. J. Algebraic Topology

(I can send it also; though I didn't read it).